# Word wrapping RSS articles in Outlook (Microsoft 365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Using **Outlook as part of the Microsoft 365 package**, viewing RSS feeds, I find that the text is not wrapped to the screen, and so each paragraph is on a single line.  You have to scroll horizontally backwards and forwards to read the feed.

[image: screen grab of an RSS Article being viewed]

I know I can click to view the article in a browser, but I don't necessarily want to do that.  It would be more efficient to just click the next article in Outlook when I want to read the next one, rather than keep switching to browser then back to Outlook.

How do I get the text to wrap?  Microsoft's [Change settings for RSS feeds](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-settings-for-rss-feeds-36101399-e467-4178-a08a-f45a5f67ce87) doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there's an option to change the setting of automatically wrapping. It's suggested that you could go to File>Options>Mail>Message format and change the character number to check if there're any differences.
[image]

If it doesn't work, please refer to this article which mentions some factors that affect the normal application of this option: [Wrapping text automatically option doesn’t seem to work](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/wrap-text-automatically-doesnt-work).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warms thanks.